# Struts 2 #{} giving compilation error in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, maven-2, netbeans-7.3

I'm using Netbeans 7.3 and I've created a maven Struts 2.3 project.

Everything else seems fine, except when I write in JSP something like this :

```
<s:select list="#{'-1':'All Activity','0':'Posts Only','1':'Trades Only'}"
```

The above code gives error in JSP. Although it used to work fine in 6.9 
Seems like a bug to me. Any help would be really appreciated.

I've already posted a comment about it on the plugin page, although doesn't seem to me like a plugin issue or so, since maven has nothing to do with NB plugins AFAIK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [netbeans 7.0 shows error in Struts2 select tag .. netbeans version 6.9 does not show this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939413/netbeans-7-0-shows-error-in-struts2-select-tag-netbeans-version-6-9-does-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above the list is populated using OGNL expression. That is valid expression, however IDE not always has support it since the OGNL version and plugin version may mismatch. You can always exclude it from validation. But it's not the major problem and you could not pay attention to it.

This example uses the same collection and looks fine

```
<s:select list="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{'-1':'All Activity','0':'Posts Only','1':'Trades Only'}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the information and I also managed to find a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939413/netbeans-7-0-shows-error-in-struts2-select-tag-netbeans-version-6-9-does-not