# showing error for struts2 select in netbeans

Tags: java, select, netbeans, struts2

when I use the below code in Netbeans IDE, I'm getting error indication in Netbeans. but the code works fine. Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting error warning in Netbeans. is there any solution for this

The error warning is in `list="#{'01':'Jan', '02':'Feb'}"`

```
<s:select label="Months"
       name="months"
       headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Month"
       list="#{'01':'Jan', '02':'Feb'}"
       value="selectedMonth"
       required="true"
/>
```

The error indication message is given below

```
Encountered ":" at line 1, column 7.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" .....
```

Comment: It might be netbeans problem

Comment: no when i tried in MyEclipse too i'm getting the same thing.....i think so it might occurs when it encounters the # character.......is there any solution for this

Comment: I am using netbeans7.4 it is showing error indication on above type code but no error on run

Comment: What is the description of the error/warning?

Comment: description is ---------- `Encountered ":" at line 1, column 7.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" .....`

Comment: possible duplicate of [netbeans 7.0 shows error in Struts2 select tag .. netbeans version 6.9 does not show this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939413/netbeans-7-0-shows-error-in-struts2-select-tag-netbeans-version-6-9-does-not)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 7 uses JSP EL 2.1 which uses the # character now.

Probably the easiest solution at this time is to add the class of the map:

```
#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{ "foo" : "foo value", "bar" : "bar value" }
```

See the answer : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971445/2764279)